# Java 8 swing poor performance with d3d

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a big swing desktop application. The switch to java 8 brought a massive performance problem with JTextFields on Intel HD Family (Windows 7) notebooks.

We discovered that disabling the d3d pipeline solved the performance problem. The question is: What happens on windows if you disable the d3d pipline? What pipeline does swing use? OpenGL?

Switch used: 
`-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` How is it possible that disabling this pipline on windows improves performance on windows?

Comment: You're disabling the Direct3d pipeline for your Swing application, not all of Windows. Swing GUI's rely on 2D graphics to paint, and it's possible that Direct3d on Windows 8 is slower to render 2D graphics.  I added the switch to two of my Swing applications, and I didn't notice any difference on my Windows 8.1 laptop.

Comment: The question is, what ppipeline swing if you disable the d3d pipeline and why does this run faster on certain notebooks then d3d?

Comment: When you disable Direct3d in Swing, the drawing is done with Java software that runs on the CPU.

Comment: Ok, thats interesting. Is there a source for this? And would it be wise to enable the OpenGL pipeline instead?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html for the whle list of d3d, 2d propeties.

Comment: Note also there is a deadlock bug associated with D3D: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077010